# Specific image and text alignment issue firefox

Tags: html, css

I've got no affiliation with this site. I do think its a very nice piece of work, but I'm curious about one alignment problem of the `chapter-nav` links in *firefox*.

For example on [this page](http://reports.originenergy.com.au/shareholder/information-and-downloads/#investorcalendar) the div with `class="fork chapter-nav"` looks right in *chrome* and *ie7*, but in *firefox 7* the text is aligned with the bottom of the image, not the center.

What is the difference in *firefox* that is causing the alignment problem? Would there be a pure css fix for this (i.e. without changing the html markup)?

[image]

Comment: In my firefox it is correctly aligned

Comment: It's aligned at the bottom in Firefox 12.

Comment: Interesting. Which version are you using @JoyceBabu?

Comment: Firefox 15 - http://i.imgur.com/OjEe2.png

Comment: @joycebabu its not the side menu its the chapter navigation below the article http://i.imgur.com/o2rRf.png

Comment: Searched for Annual General Meeting and stopped at the first one :). My bad.

Comment: @chovy I'm asking because I'm curios about the cause.